# Sum of matrix region in racket

Tags: racket

I'm learning racket and did simple code challenge in a [literate programming style](https://github.com/togakangaroo/daily-programmer/tree/master/matrix-sum-of-region) with org mode

The problem:

> Given a matrix of integers and the top left and bottom right coordinates of a rectangular region within the matrix, find the sum of numbers falling inside the rectangle.

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 0 1 2
```

should give `24` for locations `(1 1)-(3 2)` as that is the sum of the submatrix

```
6 7 8
0 1 2
```

[Here is my final implementation](https://github.com/togakangaroo/daily-programmer/tree/master/matrix-sum-of-region#org4406919)

```lisp
(require math/array)

(struct location (column row))

(define (sum-matrix-region matrix start end)
  (define slice-spec (list (:: (location-row start)
                               (add1 (location-row end)))
                           (:: (location-column start)
                               (add1 (location-column end)))))
  (define sliced (array-slice-ref matrix slice-spec))
  (array-all-sum sliced))

(sum-matrix-region (array #[#[1 2 3 4]
                            #[5 6 7 8]
                            #[9 0 1 2]])
                   (location 1 1)
                   (location 3 2))
```

Is that good? Idiomatic? Anything I could have done better?

I'm aware that for literate programming I can provide variables via tables but [the only racket-supporting org plugin](https://github.com/wallyqs/ob-racket) I found doesn't support that.